# I know how to stand by "my partner" or "your partner"?

Tags: grammar

A quick question, which one of the following is correct.

John: Thanks so much for your help Mark.

**Me: No worries! I know how to stand by your partner when he's in need.**

**OR**

**Me: No worries! I know how to stand by my partner when he's in need.**

Thanks so much guys!

Mark

Comment: I'd say neither.   "by a partner" sounds better to my ears.

Comment: 'I know how to stand by my partner when he's in need.' or 'You should know how to stand by your partner when he's in need.'

Comment: Whose partner is he??

Answer (score 1):

Technically, they're both correct. But I believe you want to use "my partner".

> I know how to stand by my partner when he's in need

The subject in the sentence is the pronoun "I". The sentence is saying that "I" know how to stand by the partner that belongs to "I" when the partner is in need. So use "my partner".

However

> I know how to stand by your partner when he's in need

Means that "I" know how to stand by the partner that belongs to you when the partner is in need. It is a grammatically correct sentence, but it means something different than the other sentence.

A similar sentence avoiding the my/your confusion:

> I know how to stand by a partner when he's in need

This means that "I" know how to stand by any partner when that partner is in need. It does not specify whose partner it is.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lumos in that they are both grammatically correct but deliver a different meaning.

I know how to stand by my partner is best, because in saying 'my partner' it's an inference to John.

I wouldn't say 'a partner' either, because that makes John irrelevant.